# nulPointException on button

Tags: android, button, nullpointerexception

i need to be able to make calls from an activity. so here is a my activity that shows details of people and i have a call button. but i get a nullPointerError when i call the setOnClickListener(...). why? thnks for any help.

```
package com.AndroidApp.pagine;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.AndroidApp.ApplicationController;
import com.AndroidApp.R;
import com.AndroidApp.XMLFunctions;
import com.AndroidApp.Login.LoginActivity;
import com.AndroidApp.domain.Anagrafica;



public class DettagliPagina extends ListActivity {

    public Anagrafica anagrafica;
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist;
    private boolean paused, newIntentSelected = false;  
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private SharedPreferences mPreferences;
    public ApplicationController ac;

    private Button bCall;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ac = (ApplicationController)getApplication();

        mPreferences = getSharedPreferences("CurrentUser", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String nome = mPreferences.getString("nome", "Errore");
        String cognome = mPreferences.getString("cognome", "Errore");
        setTitle("Sessione di : " + nome + " " + cognome);

        new BackgroundAsyncTask().execute();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();


        bCall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bCall);

        // add PhoneStateListener
        PhoneCallListener phoneListener = new PhoneCallListener();
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        telephonyManager.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

        // add button listener
        bCall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:3492395504"));
                    startActivity(callIntent);

                }
        }); 

    }



    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        paused = true;
        ac.setOraAttuale(Calendar.getInstance());
        ac.oraAttuale.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
        ac.setOraScadenza(ac.getOraAttuale());
        Log.d("DettagliPAgina scadenza", ac.getOraScadenza().getTime().toString());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (ac.isKill) {
            finish();
        }
        if (paused && !newIntentSelected){
            if (Calendar.getInstance().after(ac.getOraScadenza())){
                //torna al login con toast sessione scaduta
                ac.setSessioneTerminata(true);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sessione Scaduta", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(DettagliPagina.this, LoginActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }


    public class BackgroundAsyncTask extends
            AsyncTask<String, Integer, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(
                String... paths) {
            mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            String xml = XMLFunctions.getXML();
            Document doc = XMLFunctions.xmlFromString(xml);
            int numResults = XMLFunctions.numResults(doc);

            if ((numResults <= 0)) {
                Log.i("doInBack", "nussun risultato");
                DettagliPagina.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nessun risultato trovato", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

                Intent intent = new Intent(DettagliPagina.this, FiltriAnagraficaPagina.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            int id = 0;
            System.out.print(id);
            if (extras != null) {
                id = extras.getInt("id");
            }

            Log.i("Dettagli", "D1");
            Set<Anagrafica> anagrafici = new HashSet<Anagrafica>();
            NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("anagrafica");    

            Element e = (Element) nodes.item(id);
            anagrafica = new Anagrafica();
            anagrafica.setId(XMLFunctions.getValue(e, "idAnagrafica"));
            anagrafica.setNome(XMLFunctions.getValue(e, "nome"));
            anagrafica.setCognome(XMLFunctions.getValue(e, "cognome"));
            anagrafica.setIndirizzo(XMLFunctions.getValue(e, "indirizzo"));
            anagrafica.setDataDiNascita(XMLFunctions.getValue(e, "dataDiNascita"));
            anagrafica.setEmail(XMLFunctions.getValue(e, "email"));
            anagrafica.setTipologiaUtente(XMLFunctions.getValue(e, "tipologieUtente"));
            anagrafica.setAziendaCollegata(XMLFunctions.getValue(e, "aziendaCollegata"));
            anagrafica.setTelefono(XMLFunctions.getValue(e, "telefono"));
            anagrafica.setCellulare(XMLFunctions.getValue(e, "cellulare"));
            anagrafica.setInteressi(XMLFunctions.getValue(e, "interessi"));
            anagrafica.setRiferimenti(XMLFunctions.getValue(e, "riferimenti"));
            anagrafici.add(anagrafica);

            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("idAnagrafica",anagrafica.getId());
            map.put("nomeCognome",anagrafica.getNome() + " " + anagrafica.getCognome());
            map.put("indirizzo", "Indirizzo: " + anagrafica.getIndirizzo());
            map.put("dataDiNascita", "Data Nascita: " + anagrafica.getDataDiNascita());
            map.put("email", "Email: " + anagrafica.getEmail());
            map.put("tipologieUtente", "Tipologie Utente: " + anagrafica.getTipologiaUtente());
            map.put("aziendaCollegata", "Azienda Collegata: " + anagrafica.getAziendaCollegata());
            map.put("telefono", "Telefono: " + anagrafica.getTelefono());
            map.put("cellulare", "Cellulare: " + anagrafica.getCellulare());
            map.put("interessi", "Interessi: " + anagrafica.getInteressi());
            map.put("riferimenti", "Riferimenti" + anagrafica.getRiferimenti());

            mylist.add(map);
            Log.i("Dettagli", "D2");
            return mylist;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(DettagliPagina.this);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            progressDialog.setProgress(0);
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {

            final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(DettagliPagina.this,  mylist, R.layout.dettagli,
                    new String[] { "nomeCognome", "dataDiNascita",
                            "tipologieUtente", "aziendaCollegata", "email",
                            "telefono", "cellulare", "interessi", "indirizzo",
                            "riferimenti" },
                    new int[] { R.id.tvNomeCognome, R.id.tvDataDiNascita,
                            R.id.tvTipologiaUtente, R.id.tvAziendaCollegata,
                            R.id.tvEmail, R.id.tvTelefono, R.id.tvCellulare,
                            R.id.tvInteressi, R.id.tvIndirizzo, R.id.tvRiferimenti });

            setListAdapter(adapter);

            final ListView lv = getListView();
            lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ID '" + o.get("idAnagrafica") + "' was clicked.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });

            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }


    public class PhoneCallListener extends PhoneStateListener {

        private boolean isPhoneCalling = false;

        String LOG_TAG = "LOGGING 123";

        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

            if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state) {
                // phone ringing
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "RINGING, number: " + incomingNumber);
            }

            if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
                // active
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "OFFHOOK");

                isPhoneCalling = true;
            }

            if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state) {
                // run when class initial and phone call ended, need detect flag
                // from CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "IDLE");

                if (isPhoneCalling) {

                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "restart app");

                    // restart app
                    Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
                            .getLaunchIntentForPackage(
                                    getBaseContext().getPackageName());
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);

                    isPhoneCalling = false;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

here's the detail xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvNomeCognome"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                android:padding="7dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="24dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="4dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTipologiaUtente"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvDataDiNascita"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:textSize="18dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvEmail"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:autoLink="email"
                android:linksClickable="true"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:textSize="18dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTelefono"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:autoLink="phone"
                android:linksClickable="true"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:textSize="18dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvCellulare"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:autoLink="phone"
                android:linksClickable="true"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:textSize="18dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvInteressi"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:textSize="18dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvAziendaCollegata"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:textSize="18dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvIndirizzo"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:textSize="18dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvRiferimenti"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:textSize="18dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bCall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/chiama" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> That button might not be part of the ListView, just of the main layout of that Activity.

If I understand what you're saying, you have a main view containing a ListView and a Button. If that affirmation is right, then you need to use an Activity instead of ListActivity or use :

```
mActivity= this ;
Button button = new Button(this);
button.setText("push me");
button.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(mActivity, "push", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
getListView().addFooterView(button);
```

Be sure to call `addFooterView(View v)` before `setAdapter(ListAdapter adapter)`

Comment: Glad to know it. Don't forget to accept the answer for other users that had the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you forgot to call `setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);` in your **onCreate** method

Comment: no it gets called in listAdapter -  final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(DettagliPagina.this,  mylist, R.layout.dettagli,....). i've also tried with setContentView(R.layout.details) but it still gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of use OnClickListener, please try to use onItemClikListener.

You are in a ListActivity, so I think (maybe I'm wrong) that what you want is to make call with the selected row. So remove bCall and its onClickListener and try

```
getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:3492395504"));
            startActivity(callIntent);

        }
    });
```

Comment: That's for listening to a click on the whole row. That button might not be part of the ListView, just of the main layout of that Activity. We need more information anyway...

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an NPE because you are trying to do this:

```
bCall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bCall);
```

When you haven't set a layout for the screen.

That button is in your list row layout so you need to set it's function in your list adapter.

Comment: i did. its leter on in the code. final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(DettagliPagina.this, mylist, R.layout.dettagli,....)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your code, you are kicking off an `AsyncTask` in `onCreate`, that sets the `listAdaper` within its `onPostExecute` method.  Also, in `onStart` you are attempting to get the button `bCall`.

However, if `onStart` executes before your background task has completed, then you will not yet have set the adapter, thus your button will not exist and your call `(Button) findViewById(R.id.bCall)`  will return `null`

Comment: yes that could be the case. how do i solve such a probem? even if i put the button directly below the new BackgroundAsyncTask().execute(); call i think i would still get the same error.

Comment: You could move the button code from `onStart` to `onPostExecute`, so that it runs after you have set the adapter.

Comment: unfortunately i cant put it in onPostExecute becase only the UI thread can use/update/create views such as buttons.

Comment: luckily for you, `onPostExecute` runs on the UI thread, as does `onPreExecute`.  Only `doInBackground` runs in a background thread.

Comment: i keep on getting an eror though that says only the main ui thread can update the view!

Comment: One of the main points of `onPostExecute` is to be able to update the UI following the completion of the background task.  As such I'm thinking that there is something else wrong with your implementation that is causing the error you are seeing.